# Select into subdict from multiple tables

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a database structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    age INTEGER NOT NULL,
    hometown_id INTEGER REFERENCES town(id)
);

CREATE TABLE town (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    population INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

And I want to get the following result when selecting:

```
{
    "name": "<person.name>",
    "age": "<person.age>"
    "hometown": {
        "name": "<tometown.name>",
        "population": "<tometown.population>"
    }
}
```

I'm already using [`psycopg2.extras.DictCursor`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#dictionary-like-cursor), so I think I need to play with SQL's `SELECT AS`.

Here's an example of what I tried with no resullt, I've done many similar with minor adjustments, all of them raising different errors:

```
SELECT
    person(name, age),
    town(name, population) as town,
FROM person
JOIN town ON town.id = person.hometown_id
```

Any way to do this, or should I just select all columns individually and build the dict inside of Python?

Postgres version info:

```
psql (9.4.6, server 9.5.2)
WARNING: psql major version 9.4, server major version 9.5.
         Some psql features might not work.
```

Comment: postgres version?..

Comment: @VaoTsun Sorry, updated. Server `9.5.2`, I guess that's the only thing Python cares about

Comment: The SQL syntax I'm familar with would go "SELECT a.name, a.age, b.name, b.population from person a, town b where a.hometown_id = b.id". Similar postgres examples are show here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-join.html

Comment: @TomBarron Yeah but this doesn't output them as nested dicts

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen As far as I'm aware, SQL doesn't know anything about python dicts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

smth like?..

```
t=# with t as (
select to_json(town),* from town
)
select json_build_object('name',p.name,'age',age,'hometown',to_json) "NameItAsYou Wish"
from person p
join t on t.id=p.hometown_id
;
                                NameItAsYou Wish
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"name" : "a", "age" : 23, "hometown" : {"id":1,"name":"tn","population":100}}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Holy croc this is amazing, thanks! I'm not sure how the `with` works with `select to_json(),*`, but it's working. The only problem is that I'm getting a dict of dict like so: `{"json_build_object": {"name": "a", ...}}` instead of just the inner dict. I can easily strip that in Python so this is easily good enough, but I was wondering if there's a simple SQL way?

Comment: I added alias as example of how to change "json_build_object" to any other key

Comment: Yeah I had that figured already but it's still an extra nested dict. But it's really no issue, I'll just do a simple `results = [row['json_build_object'] for row in cursor]` in Python :) Thanks again mate

Comment: How can I extend this to support multiple sub tables? So if I have a `pet` table *and* the `hometown` table, how do I get both of them inside my `person` result? It seems like `to_json()` always produces `to_json` name so I can't have two `WITH`+`to_json` in same query? :/

Comment: add alias there as well, eg: `to_json(town) town_json`